# Single word to describe a single planet and all its moons?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I have a collection of planets around a sun in my game, and each planet can have a set of moons. I'd like to know how to call such a single planet and moons system.

This is in distinction to all the satellites (and their satellites) around a star. I am asking about how to refer to a single planet and its moons.

Comment: If this is for a game and the playable area or "known area" in-game is confined to the planet and its moons, you could just call it something sort of broad like _the reach_.

Comment: There's this [double-planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_planet) system that once unofficially referred to the Earth-Moon system.

Comment: Maybe useful, it relates to gravity wells - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_of_influence_(astrodynamics) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere

Comment: It's funny there's a term for all the planets and their satellites "Planetary system" and a term for only all the stuff orbiting around one planet "satellite system" but none for one planet and it's satellite system. I guess you have to use Planet xxx system.

Comment: Just call it a planet. It should be understood that planets have zero or more moons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just *planet region*?

Consider this:

> We're now passing through the Jupiter region with its remarkable
>   satellites.

The region would suggest it's a planet and a little extra. Since planet's satellites are orders of magnitude closer to the planet than any other celestial objects, it is safe to assume they belong to the region implicitly.

Comment: I think in the context of my game, region is going to make the most sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If the planet has a name, then (the adjectival form of) the planet's name followed by *system* seems common in both SF and real usage.

For example the *Martian system* comprises Mars, Phobos and Deimos. The phrase is widely used online.

*Earth system* doesn't appear to be widely used in this context. *Earth-moon system* is used in some discussions while the use of *Terran system* seems to be confined (almost) to SF.

Answer (score 3):

See **planetary system** at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_system).

> A planetary system is a set of gravitationally bound non-stellar objects in orbit around a star or star system.

Go [here at space/stackexchange and have a look.](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10845/is-there-a-term-to-refer-to-a-planet-and-its-accompanying-moons-as-a-whole-colle)

Comment: So that would be _all_ the planets and their moons, not a single one.

Comment: Right, I'm just looking for a single planet and its moons.

Comment: I'm still looking for it.

Comment: I thought the answer was "planetary system" before I saw that wikipedia page.  You could call it the **Planetname subsystem**.